# CASE statement not working when calculating age

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I am new to Spark SQL and am trying to recreate code from Netezza SQL.  I want to calculate a person's age using CURRENT_DATE and birth_date.  I can do this and it works ok:

```
cast((months_between(CURRENT_DATE, birth_date)/12) as decimal(7,2)) age1,
months_between(CURRENT_DATE, birth_date)/12 age2
```

Age 1 returns as .22, 80.00 etc. age2 returns as .21998... and 80.004.... The two different age variables are only for testing to see what might work.
If the age calculation returns < 0 (i.e., .22) I want the value of age to be one, otherwise I want to cast the age calculation as decimal(7,2).  I've tried various versions of

```
case when CAST((months_between(CURRENT_DATE, birth_date)/12) as decimal(7,2)) < 1  then 1
else 
CAST((months_between(CURRENT_DATE, birth_date)/12) as decimal(7,2)) end as age
```

But I keep getting errors like mismatched input 'CAST'
How can I make this work?

Comment: Just remove `as decimal(7,2)` in case statements.
https://dwgeek.com/netezza-case-statement-usage-examples.html/

Comment: The requirement is that age be a 2 decimal number.  How would I do that?

Comment: Also, the cast works as long as it isn't in the case statement:
cast((months_between(CURRENT_DATE, birth_date)/12) as decimal(7,2)) age1,
months_between(CURRENT_DATE, birth_date)/12 age2
These two statements work

Comment: You can use `round(months_between(CURRENT_DATE, birth_date)/12, 2)`.
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/psfa/7.2.1?topic=extensions-math-functions